# Drupal 8 FormBase. Los button siempre me devuelven valor "on"

Tags: php7, drupal, drupal8

Se que ya se han dado respuestas a esta interrogante. Pero ninguna suple mi incógnita. Lo que sucede es que estoy haciendo un conjunto de button en php, es un arreglo de 3 button con el mismo name pero de diferentes value, pero cuando obtengo el valor del button solo me devuelve "on" y no el value definido. Este es el código:

```
$form['button'] = [
                'comprobacion' => [
                    '#type' => 'radio',
                    '#name' => 'radiobutton',
                    '#value' => 'comprobaciones',
                    '#title' => $this->t('Comprobar catĂˇlogo de Productos'),                   
                ],
                'criterio' => [
                    '#type' => 'radio',
                    '#name' => 'radiobutton',
                    '#value' => 'criterios',
                    '#title' => $this->t('Buscar existencia por criterios'),                    
                ],
                'sub_categoria' => [
                    '#type' => 'radio',
                    '#name' => 'radiobutton',
                    '#value' => 'sub_categorias',
                    '#title' => $this->t('Comprobar Sub_Categorias vs Categorias mas Agencias en cantidades de Items'),                 
                ],
            ];
$var_parametros = $_POST['radiobutton'];
print_r($var_parametros);
```

Me pueden ayudar, gracias de antemano.
Salu2

Comment: Estas cogiendo parametros de una variable POST, ¿Que trae esa variable y que tienen que ver los 3 botones de arriba?

Comment: Esa variable le paso el name de los radiobutton y asi obtengo el valor del button seleccionado por el usuario. Corrigeme si estoy en un error.

Comment: Entonces el parametro post te trae el nombre del boton seleccionado?

Comment: En teoría si, pero al mostrar la variable var_parametro con un print_r solo me muestra on no el value del button

Comment: Entonces me da que el problema viene de HTML, ¿puedes enseñarnos el código?

Comment: El código html esta embebido en el php, dentro del mismo php yo uso las etiquetas html y asi construyo el formulario de button. En ese codigo esta todo.

Comment: pregunta para el `#` antes de los attributos? segundo dices que tu error es que envia siempre `on` pero no sabemos ni como se pinta en el documento! te recomiendo adjuntar el codigo html de como se construyen tus botones ya que la informacion proporcionada es muy pobre te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: El formulario se pinta con el código que les muestro, el simbolo # mas la etiqueta html basta para pintar los button, el problema radica en la obtención de los valores. No puedo dejar todo el codigo en un comentario

Comment: Esta función php me permite crear el formulario desde el php unicamente, sin necesidad de abrir etiquetas html para pintar el formulario de button.
Acotar al comentario que estoy trabajando en drupal 8 con las dll Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase; Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface y la de Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface.

Answer (score 0):

Vale ahora que ya sabemos que es drupal 8, creo que estás buscando algo como esto:

```
$form['button']['botones'] = [
                'comprobacion' => [
                    '#type' => 'radios',
                    '#name' => 'radiobutton',
                    '#default_value' => 'comprobaciones',
                    '#title' => , 
                    '#options' => [
                        'comprobaciones' => $this->t('Comprobar catĂˇlogo de Productos'),
                        'criterios' => $this->t('Buscar existencia por criterios'),
                        'sub_categorias' => $this->t('Comprobar Sub_Categorias vs Categorias mas Agencias en cantidades de Items'),
                    ]                  
                ]
            ];

$var_parametros = $_POST['radiobutton'];
print_r($var_parametros);
```